# Firebase Notifications Only Appearing on One Device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to integrate notifications for the first time into my app development using Firebase. My problem is that the notifications seem to only be received on my device and no one else's device. I double checked and the .p12 file is defiantly for the Apple Push Services. Any ideas?? Thanks in Advance

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, .badge, .sound]

    let pushNotificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types : notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("tokenRefreshNotification:")), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

    return true
}
```

Comment: How are you sending a notification? Also, have you ever heard of OneSignal? It's a really good tool to handle any kind of notifications. ( mainly when you are dealing with chats or users notifications)

Comment: I'm sensing through the Firebase site. Also no I haven't - I will have a look into it

Comment: Managed to get it working with firebase. Thanks for that!!

Comment: No problem bro!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is your app released to the App Store? I once faced a similar issue.

Please check your account on http://developer.apple.com and make sure both 'Developer' and 'Distribution' says enabled under 'Push Notifications'.

[image]

Also make sure, that you have uploaded certificates for both Development and Distribution on Firebase Settings page under 'Cloud messaging'.

[image]